# I can not connect to Mongo db

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Hello I work with Mongo db.
When I try to connect to Mongo he shows me the error:

**Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP
whitelist: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-whitelist/**

I allowed access from anywhere. But it's not working.
It is important to note that on other computers with other internet networks it does work for me.

**My code is:**

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
app.listen(3000, () => { console.log("listening") })

const router = require('./routes/api')

const dotenv = require('dotenv')
dotenv.config()

const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

app.use(bodyParser.json())

const mongoose = require('mongoose')


app.use('/', router)

mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_CONNECT, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
  }).then(res=>{
          console.log("DB Connected!")
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log(Error, err.message);
  })
```